# cannot create group by to my sub query in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, presto

I have this query:

```
select *
from(
select record_id, hood_id, city_id, TotalDays
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by record_id order by end_date desc) rn,
        sum(date_diff('day', start_date, end_date)) over(partition by record_id) as TotalDays
    from ads 
    where del_col = false
)
where rn = 1
union  
select record_id, hood_id, city_id, TotalDays
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by record_id order by end_of_life desc) rn,
        sum(date_diff('day', start_date, end_of_life)) over(partition by record_id) as TotalDays
    from ads 
    where del_col = true
)
where rn = 1)
where record_id = 146 and TotalDays <= 60 and TotalDays >= 0
group by record_id, hood_id, city_id, TotalDays
```

and the output its:

| record_id | hood_id | city_id | TotalDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 146 | 3 | 12 | 30 |
| 146 | 3 | 12 | 10 |

I want this output:

| record_id | hood_id | city_id | TotalDays |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 146 | 3 | 12 | 40 |

someone have a good idea to solution this problem?

Comment: With `group by record_id, hood_id, city_id, TotalDays` you say you want one result row per `record_id + hood_id + city_id + TotalDays`. But you want a result row per `record_id + hood_id + city_id` only. Hence: `group by record_id, hood_id, city_id`. And then use `SUM` to add up the total days per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to add TotalDays using the `SUM` function.

```sql
select record_id, hood_id, city_id, SUM(TotalDays) as TotalDays
from(
select record_id, hood_id, city_id, TotalDays
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by record_id order by end_date desc) rn,
        sum(date_diff('day', start_date, end_date)) over(partition by record_id) as TotalDays
    from ads 
    where del_col = false
)
where rn = 1
union  
select record_id, hood_id, city_id, TotalDays
from (
    select *, 
        row_number() over(partition by record_id order by end_of_life desc) rn,
        sum(date_diff('day', start_date, end_of_life)) over(partition by record_id) as TotalDays
    from ads 
    where del_col = true
)
where rn = 1)
where record_id = 146 and TotalDays <= 60 and TotalDays >= 0
group by record_id, hood_id, city_id
```